# How to do a simple find on cloudant?

Tags: node.js, cloudant

I'm creating a simple app on Node using CloudantDB, but I can't find how could a do a simple find searching an user by email.

On MongoDB I just do: db.find( { email : "email@email.com" } );

I thought the same could be done on Cloudant, but I found nothing about it on Cloudant Documentation (https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html) or on github examples (https://github.com/david-araujo/nodejs-cloudant).

Follow my code:

```
Cloudant = require('cloudant')

const DB_CONN = {
        account : 'user.cloudant.com',
        password: 'clodantpass'
};

let cloudant = Cloudant(DB_CONN);
let db = cloudant.use('teste');

// SIMPLE INSERT
db.insert( {name : 'test', email : 'email@email.com'}, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
} );

// SIMPLE FIND
???
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Cloudant Query](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html) to do simple, MongoDB-style queries:

```
var query = {
  "selector": {
    "email" : "email@email.com" 
  }
};

db.find(query, function(err, data) {
  // 'data' contains results
});
```

See [here](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/cloudant/get-started/use-cloudant-query/) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help Glynn. My only concern is that I found nothing about query strings. I believe that the official documentation could be better.

Comment: The "Selector Syntax" section is your best bet: https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#selector-syntax

Comment: The official documentation for the Cloudant npm package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant states: 'To query using the index, use the .find() method. ie `db.find({selector:{name:'Alice'}}, function(er, result){});` here, the selector can be any query valid on Cloudant query at the above link.